# XNA 3D Movement towards where the player is looking at

Tags: c#, 3d, rotation, xna

So I have X, Y, and Z variables and `lookAt.X`, `lookAt.Y`, and `lookAt.Z`. The `lookAt` is a vector which is where the player is looking. The X, Y, and Z are where the player is. I add rotation by doing the following:

```cs
// Update rotation
if (key.IsKeyDown(Keys.Left))
    rotation += (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;
if (key.IsKeyDown(Keys.Right))
    rotation -= (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;
if (key.IsKeyDown(Keys.Up) && Math.Cos(rotation2) <= 0.8f)
    rotation2 += (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;
if (key.IsKeyDown(Keys.Down) && Math.Cos(rotation2) >= -0.8f)
    rotation2 -= (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;

// Calculate lookAt from rotation
lookAt.X = (float)Math.Cos(rotation);
lookAt.Y = (float)Math.Sin(rotation);
lookAt.Z = (float)Math.Cos(rotation2);
```

Now what I want to do is make the player move where they are looking, like in a First Person Shooter. Additionaly, I make the view matrix by doing the following:

```cs
view = Matrix.CreateLookAt(new Vector3(X - 10, Y - 10, Z - 10), new Vector3(lookAt.X, lookAt.Y, lookAt.Z), Vector3.UnitZ);
```

If anybody needs any extra code, just ask. Thanks!

Comment: `lookAt` points in the direction you look at, can't you simply `Normalize` it and use that direction to move your player?

Comment: Thanks! I tried it and it worked! I am new so I had never heard of Normalize before!

Comment: I should have written it as an answer :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `lookAt` points in the direction you look at, you can simply `Normalize` it and use that direction to move your player.

Answer (score 0):

Just so this is an official answer, pinckerman said:

```
    "lookAt points in the direction you look at, can't you simply Normalize it and use that direction to move your player? – pinckerman 28 mins ago"
```

I have tried this and it is a working answer. Thanks to him and I hope this will help others.